# Using Semantic UI Search with CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, semantic-ui

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong exactly but I've been on this for hours, when it's supposed to be relatively straightforward. Here's my html;

```
            <div class="ui search focus">
                <div class="ui left icon input">
                    <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search GitHub" autocomplete="off">
                    <i class="github icon"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="results"></div>
            </div>
```

And here's my script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $('.ui.search')
            .search({
             apiSettings: {
                 url: '//api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}'
             },
             fields: {
                 results : 'items',
                 title   : 'name',
                 url     : 'html_url'
             },
             minCharacters : 3
          });
});
```

This is exactly from the examples page: https://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#/examples
When I try to load local data in the form of

```
  var content = [
        { title: 'Andorra' },
        { title: 'United Arab Emirates' },
        { title: 'Afghanistan' },
        { title: 'Antigua' },
        { title: 'Anguilla' },
         // etc
  ];

   $('.ui.search')
       .search({
           source: content
   });
```

It works, no problems, however loading external content like in the first snippet shows **No results found** and when I check the network tab in Network in Browser Dev tool, I see a 307 Internal Redirect on the request and another with a 200 Ok request which apparently gets the data from Github. Obviously I'm missing something here and will really appreciate some guidelines please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this using Url helper

```
url: "<?= $this->Url->build('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}', true); ?>"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Now I do not get the 307 anymore and the results still there, no more duplicate calls. But the dropdown still doesn't show the results, I get No results found. Any more guidance please?

Comment: what did you search? using this url `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q={query}` it should works

Comment: I do get the right response from the request. I guess the issue now s for me tp figure out how to give the Semantic UI search module the data it expects so I can see what I expect